# Single line if containing method call

Tags: java

I have a method which conditionally calls another. For example:

```
public boolean contionallyDoSomething(boolean something){
    boolean didSomething = false;
    if(something){
        theSomething();
        didSomething = true;
    }
    return didSomething;
}

public void theSomething(){
    //do something
}
```

I figured I could re-write this to:

```
public boolean contionallyDoSomething(boolean something){
    boolean didSomething =something && theSomething();
    return didSomething;
}

public boolean theSomething(){
    //do something
    return true;
}
```

The second method feels a lot neater and I personally like it. However I'm a little weary of writing code like this is it may come back to bite me. What are the down sides? What are the advantages / disadvantages?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you want "didSomething" to be initialized to false in the first section?

Comment: indeed. corrected thanks

Comment: Your code is invalid, as `theSomething()` returns void - you can't use it as the RHS of the `&&` operator.

Comment: This is mostly subjective, but I would chew out anyone on my team who wrote the second method in preference over the first. It's needlessly "clever" and unclear. Also, as the previous comments have already pointed out, it's much more bug-prone.

Comment: Assuming you changed `theSomething` to actually return a boolean, the second way is less readable and won't support cases where multiple statements need to be executed as a result of the if check.

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation is reasonable in some cases, but readability depends on specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest downside to this code especially if it is committed to a shared repository is readability. The `if statement branching` easily renders intent where-as the compacted code requires a second look (for mere mortals) to decipher what it is doing.

As for the advantages, well, you write less code and to some extent the compiler optimizes it to run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

So it will not bite you in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean contionallyDoSomething(boolean something) {
    if (something) {
        theSomething();
    }
    return something;
}
```

Surely this makes more sense, instead of returning a second boolean which will be the same as the one passed through?

Comment: I've corrected it now. Sorry...too much ctrl+z/y!

Comment: You're missing the point, you still end up with two boolean values that are the exact same. `something` and `didSomething` will never differ.

Comment: of course they will in the case. But the symantics are different.

Answer (score 0):

You're wading into subjective waters. All the pros and cons are to do with readability. Personally, I'd take it a step further and write it as:

```
public boolean contionallyDoSomething(boolean something) {
    return something && theSomething();
}
```

But I find tightness in code increases readability. Others may (and will) disagree.